# Link does not work on CSS/HTML template

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, href

I am using this template

https://codepen.io/candroo/pen/wKEwRL

But the link on button does not work. The close the animation without go to the page.

If I disable the js script the links works, so, I suspect that is something with the Js. script, but I could not find the error.

One card code:

```
 <div class="card-flap flap1">
      <div class="card-description">
        This grid is an attempt to make something nice that works on touch devices. Ignoring hover states when they're not available etc.
      </div>
      <div class="card-flap flap2">
        <div class="card-actions">
          <a href="#" class="btn">Read more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var zindex = 10;

  $("div.card").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var isShowing = false;

    if ($(this).hasClass("show")) {
      isShowing = true



    }


    if ($("div.cards").hasClass("showing")) {
      // a card is already in view
      $("div.card.show")
        .removeClass("show");

      if (isShowing) {
        // this card was showing - reset the grid

        $("div.cards")
          .removeClass("showing");
      } else {
        // this card isn't showing - get in with it
        $(this)
          .css({zIndex: zindex})
          .addClass("show");

      }

      zindex++;

    } else {
      // no cards in view
      $("div.cards")
        .addClass("showing");
      $(this)
        .css({zIndex:zindex})
        .addClass("show");

      zindex++;
    }

  });
});
```

Comment: Link? `<a href="#" class="btn">Read more</a>` what link?

Comment: What do you mean by link does not work?

Comment: Simply remove `e.preventDefault();` :) and remove `href="#"` from your arrow buttons

Comment: Plus your href is a '#', which doesn't redirect to anything

Comment: Sorry,, any link in "href". The button do not goes to the link, but close the card. Thank you @RokoC.Buljan, worked!

Comment: @Gergian you're welcome.

Comment: @Gergian as roko said, remove e.preventDefault(); and add some href url to buttons and it will navigate as required.